# How to check if an object key is the same as another object value

Tags: reactjs

I have an object called

```
const nameDef = {
REASONABLE: "Yes it is",
COMPLETE: "No it is not"
}
```

and another Object

```
const data = {
Typical_dq_domain: "REASONABLE,
Typical_dq_domain: "COMPLETE"

}
```

I want to be able to lookup and check with the typical_dq_domain value matches the key in the nameDef object and this will print out the value from the nameDef object. for example.

REASONABLE: "Yes it is"

Comment: yes, yes i am..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In JavaScript, you can access object properties either through dot notation, or bracket notation.

For example, to access the `REASONABLE` property of your `nameDef` object:

```
// dot notation
const value1 = nameDef.REASONABLE

// bracket notation
const value2 = nameDef["REASONABLE"]
```

If `value2` is `undefined`, it means that either `nameDef` does not contain the property `REASONABLE`, or that the value of the `REASONABLE` property is `undefined`.

Therefore, you can try something like this:

```
// value is "Yes it is"
const value = nameDef[data.Typical_dq_domain]

// Check the value is not undefined
const keyExists = value !== undefined
```